# Scroll to the bottom of the page & check if at the end Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

So I am very confused as to why this code isn't working.

This is what this code does...

1. scroll down using key down;
2. capture page height before scrolling down;
3. check if the old height equals the new height;
4. set old height after scrolling down;
5. if page height was the same before and after scrolling, return true, and stop scrolling;

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var reachedEnd = false;
var newHeight = js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
var oldHeight = js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

    while (!reachedEnd)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.End);
        Thread.Sleep(2);
        newHeight = js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

        if (oldHeight == newHeight)
        {
            reachedEnd = true;
        }
        else
        {
            oldHeight = newHeight;
        }
    }
```

So the problem is old and new height are equal at the end of the page, but it's not returning true.

Any thoughts on this? I've been trying to figure this out for 3 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

To scroll down to the end of the page you can use just this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach worked for me, thanks. This fixes exit from loop:

```
var reachedEnd = false;
var newHeight = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return  document.getElementById('liveFrame').scrollHeight");
var oldHeight = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('liveFrame').scrollHeight");

screens.Add(new ContentFile(GetUrlScreenshot(left, top, width, height)));
while (!reachedEnd)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("liveFrame")).SendKeys(Keys.End);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    screens.Add(new ContentFile(GetUrlScreenshot(left, top, width,    height)));

    newHeight = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('liveFrame').scrollHeight");
    if (oldHeight == newHeight)
    {
       reachedEnd = true;
    }
    else
    {
        oldHeight = newHeight;
    }
}
```

The problem was in casting to long.